# System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted - which Thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets

I have a web site which continuously reads data from another site and plots that information on a map.
I have a socket started as

```
client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                    new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
```

ReceiveCallback reads  the data and dumps it in a Queue for  another thread to analyse and then 
sets the waithandle to start that thread.

```
readBytesWaitHandle.Set();
```

Very rarely I am getting the following error

```
System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.
   at System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOneNative(SafeHandle waitableSafeHandle, UInt32      millisecondsTimeout, Boolean hasThreadAffinity, Boolean exitContext)
   at System.Threading.WaitHandle.InternalWaitOne(SafeHandle waitableSafeHandle, Int64 millisecondsTimeout, Boolean hasThreadAffinity, Boolean exitContext)
   at System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOne(TimeSpan timeout, Boolean exitContext)
   at WebAPRS.PacketListener.readBytesBuffer() in c:\Users\Alan\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WebAPRS\WebAPRS\PacketListener.cs:line 274
```

The question is - which thread is aborting? The one running `ReceiveCallback` or the one waiting on 
`ReceiveCallback` to set the wait handle.

Thanks

Alan

Edit Here is the code for ReceiveCallback

```
// run by the client thread (which is implicitly created)
    private void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            if (restarting) return;

            // Retrieve the state object and the client socket 
            // from the asynchronous state object.
            timeSpanSinceLastBytes = DateTime.Now - timeSinceLastBytes;
            timeSinceLastBytes = DateTime.Now;
            var state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;

            if (!state.workSocket.Connected)
            {
                reStartClient("Error: state.workSocket.Connected =false - Restarting");
                return;
            }

            var client = state.workSocket;

            // Read data from the remote device.
            var bytesRead = client.EndReceive(ar);

            if (bytesRead == 0)
            {
                reStartClient("ERROR: bytes==0 - Restarting");
                return;
            }

            // quickly store the buffer
            storeBytes buff = new storeBytes(state.buffer, bytesRead);
            byteQueue.Enqueue(buff);
            string data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
            new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
            // setoff the readBytes Thread
            readBytesWaitHandle.Set();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            reStartClient("ReceiveCallback failed : " + e.ToString());
        }
    }
```

You will see I have tried to catch every every eventuality I can think of. It often fails with zero bytes read and is restarted OK. (I check to see that the restart process is not ongoing at the beginning)

The catch block is not catching this error.
My site was just dying (maybe once every 12 hours) so i have another thread running that checks 
the health of the thread reading the output from ReceiveCallback every 30secs and it printed out the error message above.
The code for that is :

```
private void checkRunning(object state)
    {
        if(! ((packetListener.readBytes.ThreadState == ThreadState.Running)||(packetListener.readBytes.ThreadState == ThreadState.WaitSleepJoin)))
        {
            packetListener.appendToDebugFile("readBytes thread not running "+packetListener.readBytes.ThreadState.ToString());
        }
        if(! ((packetListener.readStrings.ThreadState == ThreadState.Running) || (packetListener.readStrings.ThreadState == ThreadState.WaitSleepJoin)))
        {
            packetListener.appendToDebugFile("readStrings thread not running " + packetListener.readStrings.ThreadState.ToString());
        }
        if (packetListener.timeSpanSinceLastBytes > TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30))
        {
            packetListener.appendToDebugFile("bytes not seen for " + packetListener.timeSpanSinceLastBytes.ToString());
        }
        packetListener.appendToDebugFile("Threads running OK");
    }
```

Comment: You are doing it wrong, post the code in your ReceiveCallback() method.

Comment: is it asp.net or winforms or wpf? I assume a web application, if so then probably read this too [Why is my asp.net application throwing ThreadAbortException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12476/why-is-my-asp-net-application-throwing-threadabortexception)

Comment: Thank you for answering. Here is the code for ReceiveCallback

Comment: I do not use Response.Redirect at all. It is a web application. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are getting timed out. Increase the ExecutionTimeout, as it worked for me and others using  `AsyncCallback` and receiving this very error you posted.

```
<compilation debug="false"></compilation>
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="1800"/> //1800 seconds - 30 minutes.
```

Here is a walk-through for [where to make the above changes](http://weblogs.asp.net/aghausman/prevent-request-timeout-in-asp-net) and here is a [similar situation to yours getting resolved](http://forums.asp.net/t/1786873.aspx?Thread%20Was%20Aborted%20ERROR%20Plz%20read%20Carefully%20).